# Match Web Api Route Based on Query Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, webapi

I'm attempting to refactor a messy API controller method which relies on a switch to perform an action depending on a passed in query parameter.

Ideally, I'd like to have a method (or even separate controller) for the parameter in question.

For example, take the two following URLs:

`/example/query?q=example`
`/example/query?q=another-example`

The first, I want to match the route to a method **only** when the `q` parameter is equal to `example`.

My current method looks something like this:

```
[HttpGet("example/query")]
public string GetExample(string q)
{
    switch (q)
    {
        case "example":
            return "Example Text";

        case "another-example":
            return "Another Example Text";
    }
}
```

This works but it messy and I'd like to refactor it to something like this:

```
[HttpGet("example/query?q=example")]
public string GetExample(string q)
{
    return "Example Text";
}

[HttpGet("example/query?q=another-example")]
public string GetAnotherExample(string q)
{
    return "Another Example Text";
}
```

Not surprisingly, I know I can't use the `HttpGet` in this way, neither can I use `Route`, as this throws the following error:

`The literal section 'query?q=example' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character.`

My question is, can I refactor the code closer to the second example shown above, preferably using attributes in the controller.

Comment: I think it's debatable if the second example is less "messy". I'd say it's even harder to maintain than the first. Could this perhaps be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? What is `GetExample` actually doing and does it really make sense to split it into multiple "actions" - as in: are they actually different actions?

Comment: I agree with Xerillio, but I suppose you could [use a regex constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints) that matches your values.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Xerillio - the switch currently has 8 cases due to external requirements. It's not the end of the world and while some of the actions are pretty similar, for two of them a quite different set of data is returned. Feels less maintainable to me because of it.

Comment: @Crowcoder Is it possible to use a regex constraint for a query parameter? I did look at this and thought I'd only be able to do that for a path parameter.

Comment: @0Neji could be, I'm not sure

Comment: Switch statements are inherently bad choices for evolving functionality. Replacing it with multiple controller actions just seems like a more verbose switch statement. It's hard to say without seeing the actual code in question, but I imagine you could replace it with a factory class and service classes that returns the stuff you need.

Comment: The way `q` is used here indicates that it should actually be an enum and not a string or perhaps a combination of both.